# In my Vue 3 app, all the Typescript files turn out to be accessible from the browser console

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have built my first Vue3 js app, using Typescript, and I find that all the Typescript files are available to browse (for anyone) through the Sources tab of the browser console. All the code comes out clear and readable.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This depends on your setup, which is unknown

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51482940/how-can-i-disable-source-maps-in-production-for-a-vue-js-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create the file vue.config.js in the root folder and add the following:

```
module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
}
```